# Don't find file when i upload image to server nodejs (use multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I have some problems with my server nodejs when i upload a image by multer.
https://github.com/expressjs/multer
When i go to folder uploads, i don't see my file uploaded!

My code:

```
app.use(multer(
    {
        dest: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'),
        inMemory: true,
        includeEmptyFields: true,
        onFileUploadStart: function (file, req, res) {
            console.log('onFileUploadStart');
            console.log(file);
        },
        onFileUploadData: function (file, data, req, res) {
            console.log('onFileUploadData');
            console.log(file);
        },
        onFileUploadComplete: function (file, req, res) {
            console.log('onFileUploadComplete');
            console.log(file);
        },
        limits: {
            fieldNameSize: 999999999,
            fieldSize: 999999999
        },
        onParseStart: function() {
            console.log('Starting to parse request!');
        },
        onParseEnd: function(req, next) {
            console.log('Done parsing!');
            next();
        },
        onError: function(e, next) {
            if (e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
            }
            next();
        }
    }));
```

And route: (I received file from client)

```
router.post('/newapi/addimages',function(req,res){
    try{
         // fileName = file.name, file name passed by client. Not used here. We use the name auto-generated by Node
        var file = req.files.file;
        var filePath = file.path;
        var lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("/");
        var tmpFileName = filePath.substr(lastIndex + 1);
        var image = req.body;
        image.fileName = tmpFileName;
        return res.send({ok:'heyyou'});
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.send({ok:'heyyou'});
    }
});
```

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have the `inMemory` option set to `true`. This option makes the image stay in the process memory instead of piping it to the filesystem and is accessible through the `req.files.file.buffer`.

Change `inMemory` to `false` and you'll be good to go.

You don't *have* to set each option, and for your application you'd be good with most default values.

```
app.use(multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads') }));
```